# Arduino: join char array to string

Tags: arrays, string, arduino, char, arduino-c++

How can I join all the elements of a char array to String with a separator in Arduino?

in Python:

```py
>>> hello = ["hi","hi","hi","hi"]
>>> ".".join(hello)
'hi.hi.hi.hi'
```

in Arduino:

```cpp
char hello[4] = {"hi";"hi";"hi";"hi"};
Serial.print(".".join(hello)); // <-- ????
```

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=461343.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use concat str i belive
here you go:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{       
char str1[100] = "Journal";
char str2[100]= "Dev";
 
  
 cout<<"Concatenated String:"<<endl;
 
 strcat(str1, str2);
 cout<<str1;
 return 0; 
  }
```

should appear this:

```
  Concatenated String:
  JournalDev
```

or the append method

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{   string str1="", str2="";

 cout<<"Enter String 1:\n";
 cin>>str1;
 cout<<"Enter String 2:\n";
 cin>>str2;
 
 str1.append(str2);
 cout<<"Concatenated String:"<<endl;
 cout<<str1;
    return 0; 
}
```

should apper this output

```
Enter String 1:
Journal
Enter String 2:
Dev
Concatenated String:
JournalDev
```

for more information: [https://www.journaldev.com/37453/string-concatenation-in-c-plus-plus#:~:text=C%2B%2B%20has%20a%20built%2Din,values%20passed%20to%20the%20function.&text=In%20the%20above%20example%2C%20we,str2%20of%20size%20100%20characters](https://www.journaldev.com/37453/string-concatenation-in-c-plus-plus#:%7E:text=C%2B%2B%20has%20a%20built%2Din,values%20passed%20to%20the%20function.&text=In%20the%20above%20example%2C%20we,str2%20of%20size%20100%20characters).

for more help search C++ which is the lang that arduino uses.